# How do I get a jquery slider option?

Tags: jquery, slider

I might be wrong, but I think this is an object made with jquery:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value:40,
    min: 0,
    max: 80,
    step: 10
});
```

If it's not just keep reading and let me know and I'll correct the question.

I want to get the content of `max` (80). I'm currently able to get the content of value, but doing exactly the same for max doesn't return 80.

```
alert($("#slider").slider("value")); // Outputs 40
alert($("#slider").slider("max")); // Outputs #slider html
```

How do I get the value stored on "max"?

Comment: check out the documentation to get max value in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the jQuery UI slider, then it's...

```
var max = $("#slider").slider("option", "max");
```

[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#option-max).

Answer (score 3):

To see all the option just use

```
   console.log($( ".selector" ).slider( "option" ))
```

You will get output like this:

```
Object {disabled: false, theme: null, trackTheme: null, initSelector: "input[type='range'], :jqmData(type='range'), :jqmData(role='slider')", mini: false}
```

Now you can see all the options it will return an object. To select a particular option just write the option name. Like To get disable value:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option" ).disabled
```

And you will get the value.

Comment: Why I get this - n.fn.init [input#pricing-slider, context: document, selector: '#pricing-slider'] ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at [the documentation for the `.slider` plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#methods) (which is always a good place to look).  When you do that, you will see this:

```
.slider( "option" , optionName , [value] )
```

Which lets you get or set a slider option.

In your specific case, you would use this:

```
var max = $("#slider").slider("option", "max");
```